# Help with interactive plot?

Tags: plotting, interactive

The following interactive plot causes Mathematica 9 to become unresponsive. Could someone please tell me what is wrong with it?

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{tbl1}, 
  tbl1 = Table[
    Tooltip[{effS, 
      B + EQ (P - P pfold) + 
       pfold (P + V) + (-1 - 2 EQ (-1 + pfold) + pfold) effS}], {effS,
      0.05, Min[S, T], 0.01}];
  ListLinePlot[{tbl1}, PlotLegends -> {"EV"},  
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Orange]}, Mesh -> All, 
   MeshStyle -> Opacity[0], GridLines -> {Automatic}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"eff stack", "EV"}]], {{B, 180, "Hero bet"}, 0.05, S,
   0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{V, 400, "Villain bet"}, 0.05, T, 
  0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{S, 1280, "Hero remaining stack"}, 
  0.05, 10000, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{T, 870, "Villain remaining stack"}, 
  0.05, 10000, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{P, 260, "Pot"}, 0.05,
   10000, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{EQ, 0.25, "Hero Equity"}, 
  0, 100, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{pfold, 0.5, 
   "Probability villain folds"}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: Change `{effS,0.05, Min[S, T], 0.01}` to `{effS,0.05, Min[S, T], 10}` seems to work.

Comment: Yes it seems to work but why does the graph x-axis show from -1 to 1 instead of from 0 to min[S,T]?

Comment: It's like @user0501 said, you have too MANY points for speedy dynamic refresh.

Comment: I also find the mistake that is causing the axis to show the incorrect range.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do to improve `Manipulate` speeds is to use `ControlActive`, which lets you set different behaviours for when a control is being moved and when it isn't.

For example, with this code:

```
ListLinePlot[{
 ControlActive[Take[tbl1, {1, -1, 5000}], 
               Take[tbl1, {1, -1, 50}]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"EV"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Orange]}, 
 Mesh -> ControlActive[None, All], 
 MeshStyle -> Opacity[0], 
 GridLines -> {Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"eff stack", "EV"}]]
```

you're drawing the first set of data when the sliders are moving, and drawing the second set once they stop. It's now much more responsive.

[image: plot]

which is an improvement on my machine, because your original code didn't produce a plot at all before aborting.

Still, I think too many points is still your main problem...